# Mysqldump, exclude data from tables by query

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

It's possible to ignore tables in *mysqldump* using:

```
mysqldump -u username -p database --ignore-table=database.table1 > database.sql
```

Is it possible to ignore certain records in tables while dumping?

Answer (score 1):

From a single table, it is easy to add

```
--where='...'
```